# Reference files in same subfolder from main page

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm setting up a Doxygen file, that looks a little like this:

```
INPUT                  = doc src test
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = doc/README.md
```

My file structure looks like this

```
├── Doxyfile
├── doc
   ├── CHANGELOG.md
   ├── README.md
   ├── STYLEGUIDE.md
   ├── doxygen
   └── logo.png
```

`README.md` looks like this:

```
# Introduction

This page contains the documentation for the project.

## Resources

- [Changelog](doc/CHANGELOG.md)
- [Styleguide](doc/STYLEGUIDE.md)
```

When I run doxygen I get the following warning:

> doc/README.md:7: warning: unable to resolve reference to `doc/CHANGELOG.md' for \ref command

and my html output contains the contents of `README.md`, but no links. The documents (`CHANGELOG.md` and `STYELGUIDE.md`) can be found under related pages, but their content is missing all section headers - as do `README.md`, apart from the title.

All other documentation (classes, etc) is generated as expected. It doesn't help to move `README.md` to the root folder.

What am I'm doing wrong?

*Doxygen 1.8.12*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what I should have done from the beginning - generate a clean Doxyfile and then do a diff with my current.

Apparently, this occurred due to having `TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS` set to 3. Setting it to 0 removed the issue, although I must admit I don't know why and I don't understand exactly how `TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS` is supposed to work.